# Is there a way to set world wrapping?

Tags: netlogo

I am writing a model that animates a network that changes layout from a tree to a Hilbert curve and vice-versa. When in Hilbert mode, I want the world to wrap like a torus.

All other times I want the world to be a box. Since 3.1 there are no longer any no-wrap distance primitives in NetLogo, but is there any way to set the wrapping of the world from within my program? Neither the user guide nor the Netlogo Dictionary mention this.

Answer (score 3):

For now, you can use `__change-topology`.  See
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/netlogo-devel/bQeerTqb-R4

Comment: You can find the full list of these `__` primitives here: https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Unofficial-features